# RSS feed for starred chats does not include starred chat posts

Tags: bug, chat, feed, chat-stars

As an example, this [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139354/discussion-on-answer-by-aaron-notes-not-adding-up-to-time-signature-with-weird) displays the following list of starred chat posts on the right column:

[image: screenshot]

However the [RSS](https://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/rooms/starred/139354) does not include links to the starred chat posts:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <title type="text">Starred posts for Discussion on answer by Aaron: Notes not adding up to time signature, with weird white oval note</title>
    <id>http://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/rooms/starred/139354</id>
    <updated>2022-10-03T11:58:36Z</updated>
    <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/rooms/starred/139354" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139354" />
</feed>
```

Comment: I first thought that it maybe had something to do with the room being "Imported from a comment discussion" but [this rss feed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/rooms/starred/139331) does work.